# MVC Razor Implementing multiple partials of same type in a View and read in controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, partial-views

I need some advice on how best to implement a partial view which is based on a list and implement this multiple times on a page.

So given this:

```
<div>
 <b>Contact Name</b>
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ApplicationDetail.Name, new { @class = "formInputSmall" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationDetail.Name)          
 <b>Current Address</b>
   @Html.Partial("_address", Model.Address)
 <b>Previous Address</b>
    @Html.Partial("_address", Model.Address)
</div>
```

I have a complex model which has a header record and can contain multiple addresses.

Model page class

```
public class EntityDetails
{
    public ApplicationDetail ApplictaionDetails{ get; set; }
    public List<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
```

Address Partial

```
@model Application.Models.DataModels.Address
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine1, new { @class = "formInputSmall" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressLine2, new { @class = "formInputSmall" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddressLine2)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { @class = "formInputSmall" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Postcode, new { @class = "formInputSmall" })@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Postcode)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryType, "ID", "Value"), "Select...", null)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Country)
```

I can't figure out how to differentiate the address being of different types, as the address table holds a different type.

Can I have some suggestions on how best to implement what I'm trying to achieve. I have no objection to it being ripped apart.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var address in Model.Address)
{
    @Html.Partial("_address", address)
}
```

Isn't that all you need? What do you mean by addresses being of different type? If you mean Current address vs. previous address vs. any other address type then I say you have different address types and you need to introduce an `Enum` for address types:

```
public Enum AddressTypes
{
    Current,
    Previous
}
```

and then use this `Enum` as a property in your `Address` class like this:

```
public class Address
{
    public AddressTypes AddressType {get; set;}
}
```

so this way you can differentiate between different address types in your partial view.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using EditorTemplates for this, rather than partials.  EditorTemplates are designed specifically for this (and similar) problems.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Partials do not, by default, address many of the problems of formatting your nested form fields to be properly read by the model binder.  You can do it with Partials, but you have to do extra work.  EditorTemplates take care of that for you.